# Авторизация по OpenID (одинаковые логины)

Tags: openid

Имеется форум, где идентификатором пользователя является Login. Хочу сделать вход по OpenId. Представим, что есть человек в facebook.com с логином "nefes" и в vk.com с таким же логином (email разные), при авторизации получается два пользователя с одинаковыми логинами. Как вы решаете эту проблему?

Я себе как представляю, при авторизации проводим проверку - если имеется такой логин в БД, то предлагаем изменить логин, но тут уже встает вопрос: смысл от OpenID, если логин приходится менять?

Answer (score 2):

Во первых, это не OpenId, а OAuth. Во вторых, по логину **не нужно** делать авторизацию. Если пользователь ВК/ФБ решит сменить логин то авторизация уже не будет работать! Это не правильно. Нужно делать авторизацию по связке провайдера (FaceBook, Vkontakte) и ID пользователя. Например: facebook:182372372 id пользователя вам вернет OAuth авторизация, а "facebook" вы сами подставляете, так как знаете через какой провайдер в данном случае проходит авторизация.

Comment: Например создатели тем на форуме, выводится их логин, выводить ID как автора темы глупо

Comment: Еще раз говорю. Логин это логин, пользователь сам должен выбирать логин, ну или если вернувшийся логин от фейсбука свободный - то можно автоматом сделать это как логин (лично мне такой подход не нравится, что бы форум за меня ник выбирал), в любом случае распознавать пользователя нужно через ID.